# django admin: how to deal with broken foreign keys in unmanaged table?

Tags: django

I have unmanaged model which looks like this:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Foo', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'foo'
```

Previous developer decided to do a strange thing: add `parent_id` field which can be either ID of existing `Foo` row/instance or 0 (instead of just making field nullable). `Foo` with ID 0 doesn't exist.

When I try to display this model in admin panel django doesn't complain:

```py
@admin.register(Foo)
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'parent')
```

What django does is just skipping `foo`'s with `parent_id == 0`. Without `parent` in `list_display` all objects will be displayed.
When I run something like `Foo.objects.filter(parent_id=0)` it returns 0 objects, but I know for sure that there are plenty of them in the database. `Foo.objects.all()` will return only objects with non-zero parent ids.

So how should I deal with situation like this (aside from making database migration which might potentially break existing frontend which is not related to django but speaks to existing database)?

Or at least how to make model manager return all objects and not just `Foo` instances with non-zero `parent_id`?

First think that come in mind is to use another model field and manually retrieve parent each time when I need it (via property or something):

```
parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: in a shell, can you `print(Foo.objects.all()).query`? It's surprising it skips instances where parent_id is 0.

Comment: query is fine, nothing abnormal: ```SELECT `genre`.`id`, `genre`.`parent_id`, `genre`.`name` FROM `genre` ```. With `.select_related()` everything is the same

Comment: In any case I would try to fix your data with a migration. Get the front-end team to check the impact (if any).